# How to optimize this linq query by getting two numbers in one call?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq

The code is as below, it have performance issue due to the same query has been executed twice. As a newbie, I am not quite familiar with the syntax.

Could someone tell me how to get both these numbers in one call?

```
var query = from p in myContext.Products
where p.Price < 50
select p;

int numberOfItems = query.Count();
var products = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just get the count from the list:

```
var query = from p in myContext.Products
where p.Price < 50
select p;

var products = query.ToList();
int numberOfItems = products.Count;
```

Comment: @Selman22 - It means you only need to execute one query, which is the question.

Comment: sorry you right, you change query.Count() to products.Count :) I didn't see that

Answer (score 2):

You can get the count of items after getting the `list`.

```
  var products = query.ToList();
  int numberOfItems = products.Count;
```

`query.Count();` will execute the query for the second time. But we have the list of the searched items already. And we can get count of items in the list with the help of the `Count` property.

Comment: do you mean Count property instead of Count method ?